# MVC table sorting works fine when using route values, but not when using querystring parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

I have an MVC 5 application (C# and BootStrap) and some of the pages have tables on them of course. I have used the recommended method of column sorting that I found in a [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and it seems to work fine. It works by passing column-sorting information in a ViewBag.

Here is an example of the URL: **...localhost/PhoneDirectory/Employee/Search/chris/dept_desc**    That URL performs a search for the name chris and sorts by the Department column in descending. Works great.

And with the magic of MVC, this also works (a URL using querystring parameters instead):  **...localhost/PhoneDirectory/Employee/Search?query=chris&sortorder=dept_desc**

However when I use the second URL with the querystring parameters, it seems to break my column sorting. For example when I click on the Department column once again, this is how the URL appears: **...localhost/PhoneDirectory/Employee/Search?sortOrder=Department**  Notice how the query parameter disappears on the post back.

Here is the route that i have configured for this page.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NameSearchRoute", 
            url: "Employee/Search/{query}/{sortOrder}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Search", sortOrder = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I would like to maintain the query parameter during postback on the sorting.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the tutorial and examples provided are a bit simplistic, and in the real world your pages might have to account for a lot more behavior and edge cases than they answer to here.   This is good to demonstrate some functionality but it's only good for one shots. Generally in the real world, users continue to interact with the page, as you do.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")  
        <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
}
```

Every time this page is loaded, the input value is empty.  You need a way to set that value so when the user clicks again then the postback has the same data it had the first time.

The next step would be to save the page 'state' somewhere and send it back and forth with each request. You already do this somewhat with ViewBag, but generally we use Model Binding for this. If you continue with tutorials you should find Model Binding soon.  This tutorial does happen to save the SearchTerm.  I see further down the page (int he section where they introduce Paging), they use ViewBag for this.

```
Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
```

So at the end of your Index() action, make sure you are setting ViewBag.CurrentFilter.

Comment: Thanks @TheMikeInNYC that sent me down the correct path.  I was adding the search string into a view bag, but I was not referencing it in the column headers.  I added the ViewBag in the <th> for each column and now it works great.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Note: it really helps to view the page source to see what is going on here.  This is what I had to do... previously my view looked like this (as per the Microsoft tutorial):

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th class="hidden-xs">

        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastNameFirstName).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormattedPhone)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormattedPhone)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitle).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.TitleSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentName).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DeptSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FacilityName).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LocSortParm })
        </th>
    </tr>
```

But when I added the query parameter to the header it worked fantastically.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th class="hidden-xs">

        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastNameFirstName).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { query = ViewBag.Message, sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormattedPhone)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormattedPhone)
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitle).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { query = ViewBag.Message, sortOrder = ViewBag.TitleSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentName).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { query = ViewBag.Message, sortOrder = ViewBag.DeptSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FacilityName).ToHtmlString(), "Search", new { query = ViewBag.Message, sortOrder = ViewBag.LocSortParm })
        </th>
    </tr>
```

Now I can accept a URL like this from other systems:  **...localhost/PhoneDirectory/Employee/Search?query=chris**  and when the user clicks on the column heading to sort the results it creates a new URL like this **...localhost/PhoneDirectory/Employee/Search/chris/dept_desc** and that is exactly what I wanted.